# Creating a List in a C# Class

Tags: c#, list, foreach

This might look a very simple to others. But this is quite difficult for me. My code is like this which is for the purpose of learning C#. I would like to retrieve information from the `List<Employee>` and get the method `Display()` to work. Hope anyone would offer me practical advice.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
        employee.Add(new Employee("Sudhakaran"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Unnikrishnan"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Meenakumari"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Vijaya Lekshmi Menon"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Seetha Devi Amma"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Reghunathan Pillai"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Parameswaran"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Vani Parameswaran"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Man Mohan"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Anil Kumar"));
        employee.Add(new Employee("Athira"));

        //foreach (string emp in employee) //Not working.
        //{
        //}
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

        public Employee(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<string> ENames = new List<string>();

        public Employee()
        {
            Display();
        }

        public void Display()
        {
            foreach (string item in ENames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you `Console.ReadLine();` ?

Comment: Also, what `Display` should do ?

Comment: What is `ENames` supposed to be? Why does the constructor call `Display`?

Comment: I used Console.ReadLine() to see what will be displayed in the console windows. The Display should get the items from the FName List. I also want to get the information from the List employee in Main somewhere else where I need it.

Comment: You don't *have* a `FName`, but you do have an `EName` (which will be empty when constructed!).

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Console.ReadLine() doesn't show you what is displayed in the console, it takes input from the user in the console.

Comment: That is right. The FName defect should be rectified. Console.ReadLine() will stop the display (console) from disappearing at which point I can see the output in the console window. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see what you are using `ENames` for. You can iterate over the list with the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
    employee.Add(new Employee("Sudhakaran"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Unnikrishnan"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Meenakumari"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Vijaya Lekshmi Menon"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Seetha Devi Amma"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Reghunathan Pillai"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Parameswaran"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Vani Parameswaran"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Man Mohan"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Anil Kumar"));
    employee.Add(new Employee("Athira"));

    foreach (Employee emp in employee) //Not working.
    {
        emp.Display();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Employee(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name); 
    }
}
```

where the essential part is iterating over a list of employees instead of strings:

```
 foreach (Employee emp in employee) //Not working.
 {
      emp.Display();
 }
```

Comment: No problem - glad you liked the answer! :)

Comment: Very much sir. I Loved it.

Answer (score 5):

employee is a list of `Employee` and not `string`. Therefore `emp` must be of type `Employee`.

```
foreach (Employee emp in employee)
{
    emp.Display();
}
```

you could also use `foreach(var emp in employee)`. This does not mean that `var` is of any type, it is strongly typed.
[See documentation of var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (Employee emp in employee) // changed 
{
    Console.WriteLine(emp.name); // Write employe name to console
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Abhilash P A.